# Principal Component Analysis for a Vector with Mean 0

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

If we are deriving the first principal component for a vector $X$ with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, can we find it in any other form than $Y^{T}X$ where $Y^{T}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix? (I know this is the form for a general vector with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.)

Comment: what do you mean by "PC for a vector"?

Comment: We want to approximate the random vector X by a single straight line, which we find to be the principal component line.